# Isolated transactions and lucene queries

Tags: neo4j, lucene

I know next to nothing about neo4j. Somewhere on the Internet it was said it can utilize lucene (internally) to do fulltext search. And, as far as I understand, neo4j supports having several concurrent independent (isolated) transactions writing to DB.

Consider those transactions are modifying data which will require modifying one lucene index. Now, my question is: how does neo4j manage doing that in a concurrent and isolated way, given that, again AFAIK, lucene does not support concurrent isolated transactions (instead supporting a single transaction)?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j adds a transactional layer on top of lucene, which keeps your index updates and reads in sync with the Neo4j transactional state.

You can read more about the internals in the free O'Reilly "Graph Databases" book which you can get at http://graphdatabases.com

Comment: Thank. I tried to implement proper transaction management on top of lucene used together with another DB and my conclusion was it's impossible unless you completely avoid posting solr changes which you may want to eventually roll back. And if you do, you cannot implement 2-phase commit, without that you cannot implement distributed transaction between DB and solr, and thus there will be corner cases in which solr goes of out sync with DB. Now let's try reading that book :)

Comment: Well I just scanned that book thru. There are no mentions of lucene at all (and this problem is lucene-specific). And when they speak of transactions in that book, they apply the term only to Neo's own DB, not taking lucene's index into consideration.